How cat state is constructed?
Context:
On Wikipedia, a cat state (2-component) is defined as
$$
|\text{cat}_+\rangle = C_+(|\alpha\rangle + |-\alpha\rangle)
$$
$$
|\text{cat}_-\rangle = C_-(|\alpha\rangle - |-\alpha\rangle),
$$
where $C_+$ and $C_-$ are normalization constants and
$$
|\alpha\rangle = \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}|\alpha|^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}|n\rangle.
$$
As there is infinity sum in definition of state $|\alpha\rangle$, to prepare the cat state would need infinity number of qubits. On the other hand, becuase of square root of factorial in the denominator, it seems that only several terms of the sum have signigicant probability amplitude. This would significantly reduce number of qubits necessary to prepare the cat state. I assume that $|n\rangle$ is decimal representation of a computational basis state, so if maximal $n$ is e.g. 16, we would need only four qubits.
Questions:

Did I understand the definition of the cat state correctly?
How are cat states prepared in practice (link to a paper would be appreciated)?
Can be cat states prepared efficiently (i.e. with polynomial number of gates)?


The definition of the cat state that you're giving here is tuned to what makes sense in linear optics, not what makes sense for implementing on a discrete, qubit-based, quantum computer. Usually, the GHZ state would be more appropriate on a quantum computer (see the section in the same wikipedia article referring to distinct particles).

@DaftWullie: Thanks. So, in fact cat state and GHZ state are considered to be the same, $|0...0\rangle$ playing role of $|\alpha\rangle$ and $|1...1\rangle$ playing role of $-|\alpha\rangle$, right?

Perhaps not the same, but at least equivalent.

As pointed in comment by DaftWullie, a cat state on a quantum computer is rather implemented as GHZ state, i.e. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0 \dots 0 \rangle + |1 \dots 1\rangle)$, where part $|0 \dots 0 \rangle$ plays role of $|\alpha \rangle$ and $|1 \dots 1 \rangle$ of $|-\alpha\rangle$. Such state is more or less cat state $|\text{cat}_+\rangle$, whereas GHZ state with flipped phase i.e. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0 \dots 0 \rangle - |1 \dots 1\rangle)$ coresponds to $|\text{cat}_-\rangle$ state.
GHZ states can be certainly prepared efficiently. For the $n$-qubit state we need one Hadamard gate and $n-1$ CNOTs. In case of state with flipped phase, one additional $X$ gate is necesary. Construction of circuit preparing GHZ states is well described in article Efficient quantum algorithms for GHZ and W states, and implementation on the IBM quantum computer. The auhtors provide two possible circuits, one allowing paralelization of CNOTs. Other shapes of the circuits are of course possible, allowing to adapt the circuits to connectivity of given QPU (however, this is usually done during transpilation process).

There are also physical processes people use such as light-matter interactions https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.56.2249
